# In Jetpack Compose, how can you check to see if a screen has re-composed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility, focus

I want to be able to set accessibility focus on a Text object, but only once it becomes visible (through mutable state boolean that is remembered). This means that the screen needs to finish re-composing before we can do anything else to it.

I've set up my code as follows:

```
    var isVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
    if (isVisible) {
        Text(text = "Text", modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .focusable())
        focusRequester.requestFocus()
    }
    
    Button(onClick = { isVisible = true  }) {
        Text(text = "Make text appear and focused")
    }
```

This fails when we reach `focusRequester.requestFocus()` because the Text object isn't yet visible on the screen yet.

Is there a way to check if the screen has re-composed? So that I can do something like this:

```
    if (isVisible) {
        Text(text = "Text", modifier = Modifier
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .focusable())
        if (isRecomposed) {
             focusRequester.requestFocus()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LaunchedEffect` which triggers its block when your Compoable enters composition.

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun RecompositionSample() {

    var isVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

    Column {
        if (isVisible) {
            Text(
                text = "Text",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                    .focusable(true)
            )

            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                awaitFrame()
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
            }
        }

        Button(onClick = { isVisible = true }) {
            Text(text = "Make text appear and focused")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If awaitFrame is not enough delay, in some devices it might not be, you can use delay(100) or some fixed number to request focus after recompositoin

Comment: Would LaunchedEffect work if we used AnimatedVisibility instead of the conditional?

Comment: It should since AnimatedVisibility also uses  `@Composable content` which you can check whether it entered or exited composition

Comment: The animation works, it appears when you click the button, but it does not focus unfortunately.